# How to detect user has swiped from image to video and vice versa in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I don't want to show cameraOverlayView when user swipe the video option in UIImagePickerController but for still image it should show cameraOverlayView.
Please help me if any one know the how to detect user has swiped from image to video and vice versa in UIImagePickerController.

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        pickerController.delegate = self;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }
        pickerController.mediaTypes=[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:pickerController.sourceType];
        pickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;

CameraOverLayView *overlayView = nil;
    [overlayView removeFromSuperview];
    overlayView = [[CameraOverLayView alloc] initWithFrame:[self appDelegate].window.bounds];
    overlayView.delegate = self;

pickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here i want to hide overlayView when user select video option.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so people can see whether you doing something wrong/right.

Comment: I have added a gallery button at the right hand side on UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView but i want to hide gallery button when user select video option.

Comment: Can you show your code so i can try to help plug into things that way. Easier for people to help when you give some of your code. It could be as simple as setting the button status to hidden or it could be more.

Comment: Hi SASmith, i have edited my question please see.